# batch file- exception on first of every month

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file which deletes last modified record every day. But I want to create condition like it should delete only if last modified date is other than 1st of every month. Below is the code which I'm using to run batch everyday.

```
@echo off
pushd "E:\Sales"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do (
  if()
  del "%%F"
  exit /b
)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
pushd "E:\Sales"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%D in ("%%~tF") do (
      if "%%D" neq "01" del "%%F"
   )
   exit /b
)
```

The second `for /f` command process the file date-time `%%~tF` string, that have this format: `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`, and get the second token delimited by `/`, that is the day.

If your locale date format is `DD/MM/YYYY ...`, just change `tokens=2` by `1`. If the date format include the DayOfWeek `DOW MM/DD/YYY ...`, add a space in `delims` and adjust `tokens` accordingly; i.e.: `"tokens=3 delims=/ "`.